# My web application continues to run after stopping the debugger.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I am running visual studio 2017 community version 15.7.6.

I am running an asp.net web application in debug mode. When I hit the "Stop" button to stop the debugger, it continues to run the program. I have to close Visual Studio completely to get the program to close.

Things I have tried:

`Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects -> Stop debugger when browser window is closed` is checked.

`Enable Edit and Continue` under in the `.csproj` is checked.

I have closed IIS Express in the System Tray.

Running my application using the Visual Studio 2013 debugger produces the correct behavior, so this issue is just with the VS 2017 debugger.

Nothing works in VS 2017 except closing visual studio completely.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Have you tried create a new blank asp.net web application with Visual Studio 2017 to test it and check if it still have this issue?

Comment: Yes, and it does.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is strange. Have you hit any breakpoints when you debugging? And you said `it continues to run the program when you stop debugger`, how do you judge that debugging is still going on? .exe still in the process or web browse is open? Have you tried to repair VS?

Comment: I made the blank asp.net project count to a million when a button is pressed and write each number to a .log file as it runs. It is still writing to the log file after I hit the "Stop" button in Visual Studio.

Comment: @ChasetopherB, Does it always write information to the log files or just have a delay to stop debugging after you close the browser? Do you mean that the IIS Express was closed after you closed the browser in your side or not? Please update your VS2017 to the latest version 15.8.2, view the result again. I remember the similar issue has been reported before and was resolved in 15.8.1, anyway, if  you get any latest information, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Visual Studio just does this sometimes and there's not anything you can do about it. If it's happening consistently I would try reinstalling and/or reverting to older versions to see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the IIS Express icon in the *Notification Area* (aka *System Tray*), then, under "View Site", hover over your web application.  In the fly-out menu, choose "Stop Site".  That usually works for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me, but there is an option to Exit and that kills the application